# Error "GET http://myapi.host.com/api/user net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when using header 'Authorization'

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ionic-framework, laravel-sanctum

Im usgin Laravel Sanctum auth for my API. When i try to make a call to an endpoint that is handled by 'auth:sanctum' middleware, i cannot put the 'Authorization' header cause if i use it, i get the error "GET http://myapi.host.com/api/user net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

I tought that could be my server config but donde this with Postman and it works fine, but it does not in browser.

Does anyone know why this happends?

I'm usgin Angular in an Ionic app
This is my API call

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${await this.apiHelper.getToken()}`
    });

    this.http
      .get(`${this.uri}/api/user`, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res) => console.log(res),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
```

this is the message i get: "GET http://myapi.host.com/api/user net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

if i try a call without 'Authorization' header it works, like this:

```
    this.http
      .get(`${this.uri}/api/user`)
      .subscribe(
        (res) => console.log(res),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
```

and i get this: "GET http://myapi.host.com/api/user 401 (Unauthorized)"
so i cannot authenticate anything

Comment: Is this a cross-domain request, so that CORS restrictions would apply? https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2018/09/12/authorization-header-and-cors/

Comment: yeah, CORS restrictions apply, I have already configured the config/cors.php file on laravel, but do you know how do I respond with a header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" from the server side?

Answer (score -2):

The error `GET http://myapi.host.com/api/user net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` typically occurs when the server doesn't send any response data back to the client. This can happen due to various reasons, such as an issue with the server, network connectivity problems, or misconfiguration.

When encountering this error specifically when using the 'Authorization' header, there are a few potential causes and solutions to consider:

1. **Incorrect Authorization Header**:
   Double-check that you are setting the 'Authorization' header correctly. It should follow the format "Bearer {token}". Make sure you are providing a valid token or credentials for authentication.
2. **Server-Side Issue**:
   It's possible that the server you're trying to access is experiencing some internal problems. In this case, there isn't much you can do on your end except to wait and try again later.
3. **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Issue**:
   Check if the server has proper CORS headers configured. If the API server doesn't include the appropriate CORS headers, the browser may block the response due to the same-origin policy. Ensure that the server includes the necessary CORS headers like 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', and 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'.
4. **Network Connectivity or Firewall**:
   Verify that you have a stable network connection and ensure that there are no firewall rules blocking the request. Try accessing the API from a different network or machine to see if the problem persists.
5. **Debugging and Logging**:
   Enable debugging or logging on both the client and server sides to get more detailed information about the issue. Check the server logs for any error messages or exceptions that could shed light on the problem.
6. **API Endpoint or Route Issue**:
   Ensure that the API endpoint or route you are trying to access is correct and valid. Double-check the URL and confirm that it matches the intended endpoint.

By investigating these potential causes, you should be able to narrow down the source of the error and take appropriate action to resolve it.